# StringLength DataAnnotaion Not Working MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, string-length

I have a property in  my Model Class like-

```
[StringLength(4)]        
        [DisplayName("Price")]
        public string Price{ get; set; }
```

As you can see I have Used StringLength as a constraint for this property that its length should not be more than 4 but it works when I use decimal point like-1.23 but when I don use decimal point It takes more than 4 stringlength value.

how can I resolve that.

And one more Question:-
I want to apply validation on Hours(Property in my model class) that it is if it in decimal than it can take upto 2 digits (Max value for hour can be 24 only in a day) like(4.20) and if it doesnt have decimal it can have max upto 2 digits like(24)

I hope I am clear

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store decimal value, you should use `decimal` type and not string. You can constraint maximum value allowed by using the `RangeAttribute`

```
[Range(0, 9999)] // First argument (0) represents minimum and second argument (9999) represents maximum value allowed for Price.
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

For your other question related to hours, you can use data type TimeSpan which lets you store only time value.
You should always strive to use a right type for the data you want to store to insure data integrity and easy maintanence.